# how to add more than one value using sync () method in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

what i am trying sync more than one value in the same table so far what i have done is that i have created model of the user and university and define the realtion between them as many to many to many such as the user has many unviersties and universities has many user
in my user model i have defined the realtion such as the

```
 public function University()
      {
          return $this->belongsToMany(University::class);
      }
```

in my university model

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

i have also created a seprate migration since it is the many to many relationship 
by the name of university_user

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('university_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('university_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in my controller i am trying to update the profile of user such as

```
   public function ProfileUpdate(Request $request ,User $user)
    {
        $up=User::find($user->id);
        $up->experince=$request->input('experince');
        $up->city_id=$request->input('city');
        $up->status=$request->input('account-type-radio');
        $up->gender=$request->input('gender');

        $up->year1=$request->input('year1');
        $up->year2=$request->input('year2');
        $up->University()->sync($request->Uni1);
        $up->University()->sync($request->Uni2);
        $up->location()->sync($request->location);
        $up->subject()->sync($request->subject); 

        $up->grade()->sync($request->grade); 
        $up->update();
        return redirect(route('user.index'));

    }
```

in the form

```
  <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-4">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>Institute</h5>
                                    <select name="Uni1" id="Uni1">
                                    @foreach($uni as $university)

                                    <option value="{{$university->id}}">
                                    {{$university->name}}
                                    </option>

                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-4">
                                <div class="submit-field">
                                    <h5>Institute</h5>
                                    <select name="Uni2" id="Uni2">
                                        @foreach($uni as $uni1)
                                    <option value="{{$uni1->id}}">
                                    {{$uni1->name}}
                                    </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The problem is only one value is getting stored in university_user table not two.. please tell me what my mistake is i'll be thank ful to u regards my laravel version is 5.8..